# Analyze logs. How to filter by referce number

Tags: python, bash, awk, grep

I have got following log.txt

```
log 1111 xyzqwe
log 1111 xyzrty
aaa
bbb
ccc
ttt
log 2222 xyzuio
log 1111 xyzopa
iii
uuu
yyy
log 1111 xyzsdf
log 2222 xyzghj
aaa
ddd
log 2222 xyzklz
log 1111 xyzxcv
ffff
log 2222 xyzbnm
log 1111 xyzert
log 1111 xyzuyt
```

I need to get following results.

```
for reference 1111 

log 1111 xyzqwe
log 1111 xyzrty
aaa
bbb
ccc
ttt
log 1111 xyzopa
iii
uuu
yyy
log 1111 xyzsdf
log 1111 xyzxcv
ffff
log 1111 xyzert
log 1111 xyzuyt

for reference 2222

log 2222 xyzuio
log 2222 xyzghj
aaa
ddd
log 2222 xyzklz
log 2222 xyzbnm
```

How can I fix it by python|bash|grep|awk?

Comment: This post as too much unnecessary noise. Could you reduce it to: what do you want to achieve, what do you expect. I think it could be boiled down to sort a text file by a certain id string? or something like this...?

Comment: I need just to create analisys by reference number as Result.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've tried grep -A4 pattern, but 1111 and 2222 were mixed.

Comment: Are you asking about an **algorithm**, or do you have an algorithm already in mind and ask for an **implementation**? Please clarify this in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `awk` which saves the scope (interpreted as second word in a line that starts with `log` ), and compares it to the reference (provided as argument using the `-v` option):

```bash
awk -v ref=1111 '/^log / {scope = $2} ref == scope' log.txt
```

```
log 1111 xyzqwe
log 1111 xyzrty
aaa
bbb
ccc
ttt
log 1111 xyzopa
iii
uuu
yyy
log 1111 xyzsdf
log 1111 xyzxcv
ffff
log 1111 xyzert
log 1111 xyzuyt
```

---

Here's the very same approach, rewritten in `bash`:

```bash
ref=1111
while read -r line
do
  read -r cmd id _ <<< "$line"
  [[ "$cmd" == log ]] && scope="$id"
  [[ "$ref" == "$scope" ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < log.txt
```

Comment: Could you please explain more detaile how to work your examples with awk?

Comment: What do you mean by "work your examples" (I was using your samples)? Generally speaking, set your desired reference (in the case of awk, see `-v ref=...`), and execute the command given. It will print the results as desired on the terminal. If you want to redirect the output to a file, append `>` followed by a file name. Or are you asking how awk (generally) fetches its input?

Answer (score 1):

Here is `re`/`python` solution ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CjlKzf/1)):

```py
import re

txt = """\
log 1111 xyzqwe
log 1111 xyzrty
aaa
bbb
ccc
ttt
log 2222 xyzuio
log 1111 xyzopa
iii
uuu
yyy
log 1111 xyzsdf
log 2222 xyzghj
aaa
ddd
log 2222 xyzklz
log 1111 xyzxcv
ffff
log 2222 xyzbnm
log 1111 xyzert
log 1111 xyzuyt"""

out = {}
for g, n in re.findall(r"^(log (\d+).*?)(?=\nlog (?!\1)|\Z)", txt, flags=re.M | re.S):
    out.setdefault(n, []).append(g)


for k, v in out.items():
    print(f"for reference {k}")
    print()
    print("\n".join(v))
    print()
```

Prints:

```
for reference 1111

log 1111 xyzqwe
log 1111 xyzrty
aaa
bbb
ccc
ttt
log 1111 xyzopa
iii
uuu
yyy
log 1111 xyzsdf
log 1111 xyzxcv
ffff
log 1111 xyzert
log 1111 xyzuyt

for reference 2222

log 2222 xyzuio
log 2222 xyzghj
aaa
ddd
log 2222 xyzklz
log 2222 xyzbnm
```